# FreeIPA show all dns records

Tags: internal-dns, freeipa

Just as the title says.
I'm stuck at `ipa dnsrecord-show mydomain.com`
I get prompted for a hostname

```
Usage: ipa [global-options] dnsrecord-show DNSZONE NAME [options]
```

I've tried wildcards but it is asking for a specific host.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

```
ipa dnsrecord-find
```

Just hit enter and it prompts for the zone name